# Windows 10 UWP Not Rendering Fully

Tags: windows-10, uwp

When using a UWP app (ie: OneNote, Todoist), I have an issue where the screen will render fine to the loaded size, but if I resize the window it doesn't want to extend beyond the original size.

For example, if I open a program and the window opens to 1/4 the screen size and I hit maximize, the window controls will maximize to the full window (I can click where the close button should be and it'll work, just the close button won't be visible), but the visible UI will only fill the original 1/4 area. I can move this around and it'll move to different parts of the screen, but the visible window will still be the original size.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Broken UWP App]

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the edit, I didn't know how to embed the image instead of linking

Comment: You will be able to do that too, once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem encountered on some high-resolution monitors after updating
to Windows 10 v1803.

The poster's problem seem to be solved after updating the display driver.
It is possible that Windows 10 v1803 has more strict demands upon
the driver, so a newer version might work better.

Some workarounds that may work when a newer display driver
is not available:

- Resize the window, then close and reopen the application,
  and it might then be of the right size.
- Run *Performance Options* (`SystemPropertiesPerformance.exe`) and uncheck
  *Show window contents while dragging*, then reboot:

[image]

Comment: I'm on 1803, and yes my main monitor is 4K and then the two I have hooked up to are 1080P (3 total monitors). The zoom is set to 150% on the 4K. I'll try that out. Problem doesn't go away after reboot. If I close the program though, reopen, and resize immediately, it won't have this issue usually

Comment: You might also check if there is an update to your display driver. This is a bug introduced by 1803, and hopefully will disappear with the upcoming major Windows update, which is possibly triggered by high zoom levels on high-res monitors. The above are only workarounds which worked for some people and are not a real solution, which must come from Microsoft.

Comment: looks like there is a driver update for my card. I'm trying that out, I'll see if it helps. Thanks for your help on this

Comment: So far it's working with the updated driver. Usually it would have shown by now. I'm going to mark this as solved so you get the points. Thanks again!